# How to delete translucent grey background in Fragment?

Tags: android

I'm trying to use `Fragment`to put `ImageButton` in my app, but i don't want to see translucent grey background like this:
[image]

i want to see only round button. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put below property in ImageButton.

```
android:background="@null"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```